# Magento Error in Embedded ERP Plugin

Tags: cron, plugin

I have a doubt about 2 crons in Embedded ERP Plugin For Magento

Cron

```
update_stocks
execute_tasks
```

Whose cron execution expression are as below

```
<cron_expr>* */1 * * *</cron_expr>
```

Which i assume is used to run the cron every 1 hour
but the expression resolve to and the cron scheduler schedules these two tasks every minute , due to which i think the CPU usage of our server is going high.

My Question is whether is it intended that the above cron are scheduled to run every minute or is there an error in the expression and the correct expression would be

```
0 * * * *
```

to make it run once every hour.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Native Magento CE doesn't have an embedded ERP plugin, and I don't believe that Enterprise Edition does either. So I'm assuming you're talking about a third party module, so keep that in mind.

Yes, the first `cron_expr` resolves to running the job every minute, as you've found. No one can tell you if that's the correct sequencing or if you can change it except the original developer (or unless they spend time looking at the module's code), but you can experiment with changing it.

To change it, create a new module, and set it to depend on the old module. Then, in your config.xml, match the `crontab` configuration code, but set the `cron_expr` to the value you want.

Comment: It  is a third Party plugin name Embedded ERP for Inventory Management

Comment: @NaveenKumar Did my answer help? If so, I'd appreciate if you'd consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it...